# Disable bash script input arguments substitution

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Bash script is called by Java process like this:

```
 ./spark_submit.sh ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.address=${hadoopconf-yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:18080
```

I have to run manipulation on input parameters, so I check every parameter and rebuild the original input.

I get parameters one by one by accessing $1 value and then shift.

I don't find a way to prevent bash to resolve

> ${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit

to

> /bin/spark-submit

and

> ${hadoopconf-yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}

to

> yarn.resourcemanager.hostname

There is no option that Java process will pass arguments in a different way, for example with escape slash.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure what you want your script to see. If you want literal `${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit` instead of the expanded `/bin/spark-submit`, enclose the argument in single quotes.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts of your script. What is the output of your script, if you put `echo "$@"; exit` right at the beginning? If this doesn't print `${SPARK_HOME}…` but the actual value, then variable expansion has already happened before your script is even started, and there is no way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get this problem if there's a shell that's the parent process to your shell script, breaking a single string down into a list of arguments (and running expansions on them) *before that script is even started*. This generally happens when using a programming language's analog to the C `system()` function, which takes a single string and passes it as an argument to `sh -c '...'`.

And because the process happens before the script is started, **you can't fix it from inside the script**.

Pass a literal argument list into the JVM, and you don't get that problem:

```java
List<Array> args = Arrays.asList(
  "./spark_submit.sh",
  "${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit",
  "--master", "yarn",
  "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
  "--conf", "spark.yarn.historyServer.address=${hadoopconf-yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:18080");

ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(args);
p.start();
```

That said, your script expecting arguments in this form is a "code smell" that it likely has [serious security vulnerabilities](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) in how it processes arguments; be careful that the values passed in are audited/vetted/controlled, or (better!) have someone rewrite it to avoid `eval` usage.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it with in ' (single-quotes).  Single quotes prevent the expansion.

That is, something like:

```
./spark_submit.sh '${SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit' --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.historyServer.address='${hadoopconf-yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:18080'
```